# Why doesn't my electron app change when I change the code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, electron

App.jsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function render() {
    ReactDOM.render(<h2>Hello from React!</h2>, document.body);
}

render();
```

So, right now my friend made a React website that I have to try to port over to an Electron App that I got off of the team's Github. However, when I change the code into this:

App.jsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

function render() {
    ReactDOM.render(<h1>Goodbye</h1>, document.body);
}

render();
```

Nothing changes at all. All that pops up is the "Hello from React!" from earlier. I search throughout all my code files for any other instances of "Hello from React!" with vscode, but I do not see any. Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: How do you run the Electron application and how do you run the React one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to package your application again:

```
npm run package
```

```
npm run make
```

Then, wherever you have your application installed (pkg not app builder), go into folder:

```
/path/to/<app name>/<app name>
```

Then click file

```
Update.exe
```

Re-launch your application and it should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell the application to watch for changes ...
this is what you have to do
first : open two terminals(cmd)
then on one run: `npm run watch`// this will tell react to watch out for dev change

and on another run : `npm run start` // will start electron itself

make sure your package.json script have these scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack.common.js  --watch",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
```

// below is your main.js or index.js where electron is configured

```
const { BrowserWindow, app, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const electronReload = require('electron-reload')
require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
    electron: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron')
});
function createWindow() {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1024,
        height: 900,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
            contextIsolation: false
        },
    })
    win.setMenu(null)
    win.loadFile('index.html');
    win.webContents.openDevTools();
    // add function to launch developer electron env
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
```